# Making a tutorial (coach mark) overlay. Need help moving a view based on the position of another

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to make a coach mark over lay tutorial.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private Button button1;
    private int x;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_overlay);
       button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       x =  button1.getTop();


                  showOverLay();

    }

    private void showOverLay(){

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, 0);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.overlay_view);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.overlayLayout);

        layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                Main.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                dialog.dismiss();

            }

        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

So basically, the showOverlay method is called when the activity first starts. It shows a dialog that takes up the whole screen and has a transparent background has no title. overlay.xml seen below is the layout of this dialog.

What I want to do is dynamically adjust the position of the text view so its above the button to compensate for different device screens (in future I will add image views with arrows pointing to things so it would be weird if these arrows don't point at view they refer to).

Please note. I cannot use showCaseView because I will be targeting api 8.

[image]

The above image shows what I want to do. Move the text view that says "HEEEEEELP" to be slightly above the button.

main_activity.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:onClick="idk"
        android:text="This Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/overlayLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="HEEEEEEELP"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for reading.

**Update 2**

My OnCreate Method

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_overlay);
       button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       button1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                 top =  button1.getTop();
                 bottom = button1.getBottom();
                 left = button1.getLeft();
                 right = button1.getRight();
                 showOverLay();
                 button1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                 return true;
            }
        });


    }
```

I now have access to the co-ordinates of button1. However, I am unsure of how to go about placing the text view above the button which is able to cater for different device sizes. 
I tried playing around with the parameters of the setMargins method but its hard to judge the amounts.
I did some research and found i could use a relative layout with layout params and use fields like ABOVE etc. however this does not seem to be working as intended. The text view does not go above the button.

My code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, R.id.button1);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.button1);

textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Please note that my overlay_view.xml has become a relative layout.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you should do:

```
button1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
         button1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
         x =  button1.getTop();
         showOverLay();
         return true;
    }
});
```

Actually when you call `x =  button1.getTop();` in `onCreate()` the Button view is not yet drawn and measured, hence the value of `getTop` is 0. Try this out.

Comment: Thanks. I put this code in onCreate. I can now get the values of of getTop and getLeft etc. I had to add,  button1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this); because the listener was in a loop of some kind. Please, may you read my new update above, I was playing around with co-ordinates and the LayoutParams to try and get the text view just to be above the button.

Comment: but ran into some difficulty so I opted for a relative layout and attempt to use fields like ABOVE but that does not seem to be working either and not sure why. Been Goggleing for some hours :D .

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your showOverlay() method:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, x);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and remove this from your xml file:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: Hi thank you, sorry for the late reply. I did the changes and there were some problems. On my overlay_view xml file I had to change the layout from Relative to LinearLayout because I was getting a Cannot Cast Relative to Linear Layout. Also the value of co-ordinate X via the getTop method appears to be returning 0. The Text View position did not change to what I wanted. The changes I made are seen above at the end.

Comment: @user3364963 Have you tried to just change "LinearLayout" to "RelativeLayout" and "x" to "top" in my code?

Comment: It moves after making that change when playing around with the co-ordinates. However, even when using the co-ordinates provided by getTop (x) and getLeft(y) it still does not seem to compensate for smaller screens when I run it on a smaller phone AVD

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Dialog for such overlays, they may require a separate window. Just make you activity such that it can display a View on top of everything i.e. its content view is a `FrameLayout` to which you can easily add and remove any `View` object.

Then, you can find any other view object's global rectangle in window by using [`getGlobalVisibleRect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point)). Next, you align your help content to any side of this rectangle.

Comment: I'll research the topics you mentioned and I will get back to you with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your UI drawings after the layout completes its drawing. You can do this by attaching a `Runnable` interface on the layout's drawing thread. When you're calculating margins or paddings, you should do this after the view is created. Please see: [onFinishInflate();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate%28%29)

```
button1.post(new Runnable() {
   x = button1.getTop();

   showOverLayout();
});
```